# Chrome stable version fails to launch on Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed chrome canary along stable build on windows 7. Canary build loads perfectly, but stable version didn't launch. Is there any solution to run stable build without uninstalling canary build?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. I have both running on Windows 7, Mac OS, and Linux.

Comment: I know that. But stable version isn't starting, ironically canary build works fine

Comment: Can you give us more information about your problem and what you have tried to fix it?

Comment: I didn't do anything to solve this. Both versions worked side by side just fine. But suddenly stable version is not loading. The only thing that changes that canary version update. Can update of canary version broke stable build?

Comment: Why don't you try uninstalling and reinstalling the Canary build? It is unclear whether updating the Canary build or installing the Canary build appeared to break the stable release.

Answer (score 0):

Run the stable version from the command line. It will print any errors back. The error message should help you figure out why it isn't starting.

Also, you might run the Task manager (Ctrl-Shift-Esc) and see if a zombie Chrome process is running on your PC. If so, use the TM to kill it and you should have no more problem.